# In-scope QTimer runs on Ubuntu but not on Windows

Tags: c++, qt

I'm facing a problem with QTimer on Windows.

The context of usage is the following :

1. I read a file, line by line, and trigger a 10s timer before starting
2. If the file is processed in less than 10s, then everything is fine
3. If the file is too big, then i don't want to spend too much CPU reading it and stops after 10 sec even thought I did not reach the end

Here is the code :

```
//Function readModel, with arguments path and modelType

//Check if files exists and opens it

QTimer readPointsTimer;
readPointsTimer.setInterval(10000);
readPointsTimer.setSingleShot(true);
readPointsTimer.start();

in.seek(0); //The file is already opened if it exists
while (!in.atEnd() && m_process){ //While I did not reach the end of the file, or the user didn't ask to stop
    qDebug() << "remaining" << readPointsTimer.remainingTime();
    if(readPointsTimer.remainingTime()==0 && m_readPoints){
        m_process = false;
        m_fileReadEntirely = false;
        readCommentsTimer.start();
    }

    //Read line
    QString line = in.readLine();
    //Some process function not important for this post
}
readPointsTimer.stop();
//Some finalization not important for this post
```

The problem I have is the following : **In Ubuntu this code runs fine**. The timer is triggered and the qDebug() displays a countdown. When it reaches 0 the while loop stops as expected. **On windows the story is different. The qDebug() always displays "10000", as is the timer had started but was not counting down.**

To give more context, this function is triggered to run in a concurrent thread :

```
void ModelManager::loadModel(ModelManager::MODEL_TYPE type, const QString &path)
{
    m_loadingFuture = QtConcurrent::run(this,&ModelManager::readModel, type, path);
}
```

Do you know what could cause this behavior on Windows ? Is the function badly coded even for Ubuntu or is this some Windows peculiarity ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: For this functionality you actually don't need a `QTimer` (it's main functionality is to start some function when finished, which you don't need). Why not use `QElapsedTimer` and check if the elapsed time is over 10000?

Comment: From the docs: "In multithreaded applications, you can use `QTimer` in any thread that has an event loop." And I doubt that you have one.

Comment: molbdnilo I guess that you are right. But how come it works on Ubuntu and not a Windows ? is this the way QConcurrent handles the threads management on both OS ?

Comment: Is this a GUI program with a `QApplication` instance on which `exec()` is called? Then it would have an event loop.

Comment: It is ! It's a GUI Application with 3D render, the code in this post reads a parses the file concurrently and sends a signal when done so that the GUI can render it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having tested that hypothesis, I assume that it could be a problem that writing to the screen typically takes quite some time; to improve this, it is typically buffered; meaning that when you execute `qDebug() << "remaining" << readPointsTimer.remainingTime();`, you don't actually directly write to the screen, but instead to some internal buffer, which is then flushed occasionally (but doing that takes some time). But all that while it's still filling the buffer again; you write to `qDebug` each loop cycle, so each line of the file, meaning you could write it millions of times...

To prevent overwhelming the output buffer (and in general to avoid unnecessary excess output), I would write the output less often, say every second or so:

```
QElapsedTimer t;
t.start();
while (!in.atEnd() && m_process){ //While I did not reach the end of the file, or the user didn't ask to stop
    if (t.elapsed() > 1000)
    {
        qDebug() << "remaining" << readPointsTimer.remainingTime();
        t.start();
    }
    // ...
}
```

And while you're at that, you could even completely replace the `QTimer` with the simpler [`QElapsedTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html#restart).
You actually don't seem to need a `QTimer` - its main functionality is to start some function periodically, or when "finished". All the currently shown code uses the `QTimer` for is to measure the time that has passed since starting to read the file (by querying the `remainingTime()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I changed my code and it seems way more elegant than before. I can't try it on Windows for now but as soon as I can I'll give you an update and accept your answer !

Comment: It runs now well on Windows ! I got a problem that was coming from a not started QElapsedTimer showing an unitialized value as remaining time. (I use 2 timers, one to read points, and one to read comment. When the one for points > 10s, I start the one for comments. Before starting, the one for comments was showing >10^6 as remaining time. I now start them both at the same time, with a higher duration for the second one, which works). Your solution with QElapsedTimer is way better than the one I first had !

Comment: yes, don't forget to call .start() on the QElapsedTimer object ;) glad it works out for you!